# windows mobile 6 emulator not signed with a trusted certificate error

Tags: windows-mobile-6, windows-mobile-emulator

I´m trying to install a program in the windows mobile 6 emulator, running it as standalone image (PPC_USA.BIN). The program installs sucessfully, but when i try to run it, the error msg is:

> The file '' cannot be opened. Either is not signed with a trusted certificate, or one of its components cannot be found. If the problem persists, try reinstalling or restoring the file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The application probably requires that security be lowered. So to be able to run it, the device needs to have security lowered at least to the level at which the user is asked for permission when he/she is running an unsigned executable. In the context of Windows Mobile security, it means that the device's security configuration needs to be set to `Two-Tier-Prompt`, `One-Tier-Prompt` or `Security-Off` (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms839681.aspx) for more details).

Changing of the security configuration might require device manufacturer's or operator's assistance.

In some cases it can be done by the user. Some of them are listed below:

1. If the user has a registry editor application which can run on
   the device and can change the device registry (such application
   needs to be signed by a certificate which is trusted by the device
   though, or the same issue will repeat itself.)
2. The device has installed Microsoft Windows Mobile development
   certificates.
3. The device allows the user to install the Microsoft Windows
       Mobile development certificates.

Of the above, 2 and 3 are more than likely be the case; if so then try the following:

1. Install Windows Mobile SDK ([Here](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?familyid=06111A3A-A651-4745-88EF-3D48091A390B&displaylang=en))
2. Install `<WM SDK>/Tools/Security/SDK Development
   Certificates/Certs.cab` on the device.
3. Go to `<WM SDK>/Tools/PocketPC/Security/Security Configuration` and
   use one of the `cpf` file to change the device's security
   configuration (see the Readme File located at `<WM
   SDK>/Tools/PocketPC/Security/Security Configuration/ReadMe.txt`)

Hope this helps someone, even-though I'm a year or so late...